# On Click of plus repeat the section

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have application to enter details of person, the admin can enter details of 10 person at a time, the initial screen will have details to enter for one person, on click of a plus sign the fields should be shown to enter details of second person and again plus should populate to enter details of third person.

Could you please suggest any angular or jquery code to do this?

Comment: You `code`, we `suggest`

Comment: @AmitSoni Except for the people that answer anyways because they want to show us how good they are at solving problems. And then we wonder why questions like this keep coming back here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With angular:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="person in people">
            <input ng-model="person.name"/>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-click="new_person()">+</button>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.people = [
        {name:''}
    ];
    $scope.new_person = function() {
        $scope.people.push({name:''});
    };
});
```

You can add more details of the person inside li tag.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bpsemjh5/)

Answer (score -1):

You could do something as simple as the below:

```js
$('#cloneBtn').click(function(){
    var miniMe = $('.clone:eq(0)').clone(); // clone the first section
    miniMe.find('input','select','radio','textarea').val(''); //clear the cloned sections contents
     $('#cloneWrapper').append( miniMe ); // add the clone to the dom
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="cloneBtn" type="button" value="Add new section" />
<form>
  <div id="cloneWrapper">
  <div class="clone">
    First name:
    <input type="text" name="first_name" />
    <br>Last name:
    <input type="text" name="last_name" />
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```